# How to get information in javascript?(object c + UIWebView + AJAX)

Tags: iphone, ajax

I've already known that there is an interface in UIWebView for object c to call javascript.
And now I have a problem:
After the javascript is finished, there are some result in the javascript, and I want to get it out and use it with object c. Is it possible to get the result from javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIWebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` returns the result of running a script.

Comment: Thanks.
I've just realized this.